# Oracle plsql - want to generate and use single id for current run

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am creating a log table something like below

```
Run_id | Log_id | Procedure_name | Log_text
```

`Log_id` is a running sequence. `Run_id` is a group id for all the log texts generated by a procedure in a given run.

How to achieve this?

A procedure which wants to insert record into above log table will call a `LOG_PROCEDURE`. So I am planning to put all the logic in this `LOG_PROCEDURE`.

Example:

```
Run_id | Log_id | Procedure_name | Log_text
1      | 1      | p1             | table updated
1      | 2      | p1             | table inserted 
1      | 3      | p1             | record deleted
```

Comment: Have you thought about creating two sequences, one for `log_id` and one for `run_id`. Should solve your purpose.

Comment: Yes planning 2 different sequence. But my problem is when I enter 3 log texts I want Run_id to be same for all 3.

Comment: Run_id | Log_id | Procedure_name | Log_text

Comment: you can save the value of sequence for RUN_ID in a variable and use it for all your insert scripts, whereas for the other one you can use `sequence.nextval`

Comment: U mean global variable?

Comment: A local variable inside your procedure should be alright

Comment: So you are asking how to define a variable in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger, which will set the `Log_id` for you after each insert in the log table. Add a parameter to the procedure, which will pass the current value of the sequence for `Run_id` and each time you log in the procedure, you'll use this value. At the end of the procedure you'll just increment the variable so the next procedure will have the correct value.